# Active Record, how to make N-N relationship properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-admin

I have a N-N relationship between the tables Notebook and Part. A Notebook has many Parts and a Part can be present in many Notebooks. Here's a example of the schema:

[image]

In other approach, as suggested by AJFaraday in comments, I would have a single join table notebook-parts with a role to identify if its a gpu, a processor, etc:

[image]

How can I use the approach 2 to invoke `notebook.processor, notebook.gpu` etc inside Rails? And also I'll need to have some empty parts since some notebooks doesn't have dedicated gpu's, or maybe have only ssd's without hd's etc ?

How the model's relationship's should be?

Comment: I’m not sure why you want multiple join tables here. A standard way would be a single table named NOTEBOOK_PARTS, which could have a ‘role’ attribute if you needed to define its a processor, gpu etc.

Comment: You are 100% right.

Comment: Hey AJ, can you look the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a model for the join table and reference it in both models.

```
# models/notebook_part.rb
class NotebookPart
  belongs_to :notebook
  belongs_to :part
end

# models/part.rb
class Part
  has_many :notebook_parts
  has_many :notebooks, though: :notebook_parts
end

# models/notebook.rb
class Notebook
  has_many :notebook_parts
  has_many :parts, though: :notebook_parts
end
```

Then in your notebook model you can create methods based on part roles something like:

```
# models/notebook.rb
def processors
  parts.where(part_role: :processor)
end
```

Then make that for any other roles you deem necessary, or think of some metaprogramming loop to make those lists for you.

Comment: But how I could call .processor in a instance of notebook? Say: 
`acer = Notebook.where(name: 'Acer')`
I would like to: `acer.processor` and get a instance of Processor back.

Comment: If you have a validation to ensure only one processor is assigned to a given notebook you could use that very same method I suggested with a `.first` in the end.